# Password being returned as NULL...?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a method called `getUser` which just fetches a record from the database if the username supplied in the argument exists. Here is the method:

```
public function getUser($username)
    {
        $userInfo = array(
        'username' => $username
        );

        if ( ! $stmt = $this->Connection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $this->_info['Prefix'] . "users
        WHERE `".implode("`, `", array_keys($userInfo))."` = ?"))
        {
            echo 'Prepare Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! $stmt->bind_param('s', $userInfo['username']))
        {
            echo 'Bind Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! $stmt->execute())
        {
            echo 'Execute Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
            return FALSE;
        }

        $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 0)
            {
                $this->_user['exists'] = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_user['exists'] = TRUE;
            }

        $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        $this->_user['username'] = $username;
        $this->_user['password'] = $password;


            $stmt->close();
            return $this->_user;
    }
```

As you can see at the end of the method I return the `_user` array which I use in another method called `checkPassword`. This is where it is all going wrong, what I mean is the password is `NULL`. To make sure this wasn't an error with the query I outputted the username (which was returned from the `getUser` method) and it was correct. So I know that the query is executing and storing the values, however the password is being returned as `NULL`. Here is the `checkPassword` method:

```
public function checkPassword($username, $password)
    {
       $info = $this->getUser($username);

       if ($info['exists'] == FALSE) {
           exit('The specified user does not exist!');
       }

        if (password_verify($password, $info['password']))
        {
            echo 'YAY';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'NAY';
        }

    }
```

As you can probably guess the output I get is `NAY` even though the password is correct. When I check to see the value of `$info['password']` it is just `NULL`.

Why is the password being returned as `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query from :

```
"SELECT * FROM "
```

to

```
"SELECT username, password FROM "
```

Now if you have more columns in your users table, you might assign another fields to `$password` and `$username` variables inside `getUser()` function